# How to handle last situation from fragment to fragment in Android?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a big problem about Fragments. When I press another fragment and come same here all my changes disappear. For example I press like button and like it and I'm switching another fragment. When I come back same fragment like icon as before.

I really need this information. Please give me reference document or sample code.

Comment: If you are changing from Fragment to Fragment, it may be better to use Activity instead. If you have a view with a fragment you change, ignore this comment

Comment: If you want to keep this information even when you close your app use Shared Preferences: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html